# WinForms event for TextBox focus?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to add an even to the `TextBox` for when it has focus. I know I could do this with a simple `textbox1.Focus` and check the bool value... but I don't want to do it that way.

Here is how I would like to do it:

```
this.tGID.Focus += new System.EventHandler(this.tGID_Focus);
```

I'm not sure if EventHandler is the correct way to do this, but I do know that this does not work.

Comment: Use the Enter event.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're looking for the GotFocus event. There is also a LostFocus event.

```
textBox1.GotFocus += textBox1_GotFocus;
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for, tyvm.

Comment: I can't see the **GotFocus** event into the list of events of the Properties panel in MS C# Express 2008. I can only see **Enter** event.

Answer (score 16):

```
this.tGID.GotFocus += OnFocus;
this.tGID.LostFocus += OnDefocus;

private void OnFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Got focus.");
}

private void OnDefocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Lost focus.");
}
```

This should do what you want and [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter.aspx) describes the different events that are called and in which order. You might see a better event.

Answer (score 10):

I up-voted Hans Passant's comment, but it really should be an answer.  I'm working on a Telerik UI in a 3.5 .NET environment, and there is no GotFocus Event on a RadTextBoxControl.  I had to use the Enter event.

```
textBox1.Enter += textBox1_Enter;
```

Comment: In fact there is a `GotFocus` event for all controls but it doesn't have [designer support](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36124027/3110834). It's recommended to use `Enter`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you wrap it and declare the handling function, based on Hans' answer.

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
  public Form1()
  {
   InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   txtSchedNum.Enter += new EventHandler(txtSchedNum_Enter);
  }
  protected void txtSchedNum_Enter(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   txtSchedNum.Text = "";
  }
 }
}
```