# Why does GotFocus event keep deleting itself from Designer?

Tags: c#, winforms

I wanted to add a GotFocus event to a Windows Forms Textbox, so I used the method described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255278/winforms-event-for-textbox-focus) question; it works, but after I run my application a couple of times the piece of code deletes itself and I don't know why.

This is the code that keeps deleting itself:

```
txtID.GotFocus += txtID_GotFocus;
```

Comment: Why do you put it in designer instead of your code?

Comment: Because the Validating events work perfectly when I put them in the designer, so I assumed the gotfocus event would too. I'll put it in the code itself and share the results, thanks.

Comment: @jmcc put the piece in the code not the designer.

Comment: You are right, the designer removes the code!  Not the answer, but:  Use `Enter` event instead. Also don't touch designer generated code.

Comment: Thanks, it worked just fine.

Comment: @jmcc. you may want to mark Reza Aghaei as answered if it helped you

Comment: In which method / event have you  written this code ? e.g. be aware that there are places which are generated code (e.g. initialize components) and there you shouldn't write your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It disappears because you don't use conventions that are used by WinForms designer when you add event handlers.

It doesn't matter whether you use `GotFocus` or `Enter` event. If you (in your Designer.cs) manually add event handler this way:

```
txtID.Enter += txtID_Enter;
```

then it would always disappear from designer next time you move control on designer surface.

**You must add event handlers this way:**

```
txtID.GotFocus += new System.EventHandler(txtID_Focus);
txtID.Enter += new System.EventHandler(txtID_Enter);
```

and nothing would disappear because it's the way designer expects code to be.

Comment: The reason is what you said.

Answer (score 2):

Surely it's another evidence about why you should not touch designer generated code and should pay attention to this warning: `do not modify the contents of this method with the code editor.`

As a workaround use [`Enter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter(v=vs.110).aspx) event instead (which is recommended). Also you can assign the handler in your `Load` event of form.

**EDIT**
The reason is correctly mentioned by [nikita](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36124947/3110834), it's because you didn't use designer conventions. For more information see his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36124947/3110834).